# Set status to warning when update was not received for set time in Shinken

Tags: monitoring, python, shinken

I am currently in a process of setting up monitoring with [Shinken](http://www.shinken-monitoring.org/). For some of the checks, I am using [webservice](https://shinken.readthedocs.io/en/1.4.2/89_packages/ws_daemon_module.html) module to receive incoming status updates.

However, what happens when the last update is OK and then the device/link fails in a way that prevents further updates?

My question is - is there any way to automatically set warning states when update has not been received for set time, say 60s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is (in Nagios, anyway) called "[freshness checking](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/freshness.html)".

Perhaps Shinken also has this.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds like it! Will have a look if Shinken supports it.

Comment: Looks like it does - http://dooblem-shinken-doc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/07_advanced/freshness.html